# Azure Cognitive Services - TTS - SSML Editor

Tags: angular, azure-cognitive-services, ssml

I am working on a application where I need to integrate Azure TTS service. To make it more user friendly I am looking for a ready to use SSML editor otherwise I need to built it from scratch. So before building it, I just need to check if there is any third party ssml editor which can be integrated.

Ex : https://speech.microsoft.com/audiocontentcreation

My application is on Angular with .Net Core.

Comment: SSML Editor is integrated in the audio content creation, you can try the  simple SSML editor(https://ssml-editor.azurewebsites.net/)  allows developers to fine-tune the pitch, pronunciation, speaking rate, volume, and more of the text-to-speech output. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp

Comment: Yes it is . But I am working on a custom application where end users can generate audio files from text.

Comment: have you found any ? @Deb

Comment: No But I am in the process of building my own using java script.